# How to fix React Native android build issue "package com.facebook.react.bridge does not exist"

Tags: android, react-native

I am getting this error:

```
Task :@react-native-community_async-storage:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
/Users/Desktop/node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/asyncstorage/AsyncLocalStorageUtil.java:10: error: package javax.annotation does not exist
import javax.annotation.Nullable;                       ^
/Users/Desktop/node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/asyncstorage/AsyncLocalStorageUtil.java:20: error: package com.facebook.react.bridge does not exist
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableArray;
like 1`
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 10):

<sub>OP's solution migrated from the question to an answer:</sub>

> In your android/build.gradle, add the following lines
>
> ```
> def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())
>
> allprojects {
>    configurations.all {
>        resolutionStrategy {
>            force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
>        }
>    }
> }
> ```